# Tengo 2 dudas sobre código JS

Tags: javascript

estoy empezando con JS y tengo 2 dudas. Este es el código. La primera duda es que al probarlo al final del todo me sale "Numero matricula: 3059" el '305' es el numero de la matricula y el 9 el promedio pero no consigo que el 9 con un br salga en la siguiente linea. La otra duda seria como hacer para que los datos del alumno se los pida al usuario con algún tipo de prompt o algo asi y el los añada para luego mostrarlos. Y si alguien me ayuda con como mostrarlos, o si puede el usuario añadir mas de un alumno.

Gracias

````
        <script type="text/javascript">
            class Alumno {
                constructor(nom, ape, edad){
                    this.nombre=nom;
                    this.apellido=ape;
                    this.edad=edad;
                    this.numMatricula=null;
                }

                Imprimir(){
                    document.write("<br>Nombre: " + this.nombre)
                    document.write("<br>Apellido: " + this.apellido)
                    document.write("<br>Edad: " + this.edad)
                    document.write("<br>Numero matricula: " + this.numMatricula)
                }

                Matricular(num_matricula){
                    this.numMatricula=num_matricula
                }

                static promedio(a, b, c){
                    return (a+b+c)/3;
                }
            }

            var alu1 = new Alumno("Perico", "Perez", 20);

            alu1.Imprimir();
            alu1.Matricular(305);
            alu1.Imprimir();
            
            document.write(Alumno.promedio(10, 10, 7));
        </script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error que encontré en tu código es que inicializas a **`this.numMatricula`** como **`NULL`**, de la cual al llamar a **`Imprimir()`** por primera vez, la matrícula te retornará **`NULL`** debido al orden que estás declarando tus funciones:

```
alu1.Imprimir(); // this.numMatricula devuelve NULL
alu1.Matricular(305); // this.numMatricula será 305
alu1.Imprimir(); // this.numMatricula devuelve 305
```

Lo correcto sería enviar como parámetro al **`constructor()`** a la matrícula, quedando tu constructor de la siguiente forma:

```
constructor(nom, ape, edad, matricula) {
  this.nombre = nom;
  this.apellido = ape;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.numMatricula = matricula;
}
```

Ahora la observación que comentas sobre el salto de línea del promedio, es que la función **`promedio()`** te retorna solo el número del promedio, y esto lo estás imprimiendo luego de llamar la función **`imprimir()`**, de la cual siempre se mostrará al final de cada resultado sin dar un salto de línea. Lo correcto sería retornar el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
static promedio(a, b, c) {
  return '<br>' + "Promedio: " + (a + b + c) / 3 + '<br>';
}
```

Y al momento de llamar a **`Imprimir()`**, llames también a la función **`promedio()`** para que se muestre al final:

```
Imprimir() {
  document.write("<br>Nombre: " + this.nombre)
  document.write("<br>Apellido: " + this.apellido)
  document.write("<br>Edad: " + this.edad)
  document.write("<br>Numero matricula: " + this.numMatricula)
  document.write(Alumno.promedio(10, 10, 7)); // llamo al promedio y se muestra lo que retorna
}
```

Tu código final vendría a ser el siguiente:

```js
class Alumno {
  constructor(nom, ape, edad, matricula) {
    this.nombre = nom;
    this.apellido = ape;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.numMatricula = matricula;
  }

  Imprimir() {
    document.write('<br>Nombre: ' + this.nombre);
    document.write('<br>Apellido: ' + this.apellido);
    document.write('<br>Edad: ' + this.edad);
    document.write('<br>Numero matricula: ' + this.numMatricula);
    document.write(Alumno.promedio(10, 10, 7));
  }

  Matricular(num_matricula) {
    this.numMatricula = num_matricula;
  }

  static promedio(a, b, c) {
    return '<br>' + 'Promedio: ' + (a + b + c) / 3 + '<br>';
  }
}

var alu1 = new Alumno('Perico', 'Perez', 20, 305);

alu1.Imprimir();
alu1.Imprimir();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para escribir el promedio al final tienes que llamar a la función `promedio()` dentro de la función `Imprimir`:

```
Imprimir(){
     document.write("<br>Nombre: " + this.nombre)
     document.write("<br>Apellido: " + this.apellido)
     document.write("<br>Edad: " + this.edad)
     document.write("<br>Numero matricula: " + this.numMatricula)
     document.write("<br>Promedio: " + this.promedio(10, 10, 7));
}
```

Y para pedirle datos al usuario puedes usar prompt o con `<input />`, usando prompt sería por ejemplo:

```
const nombre = prompt("Dime tu nombre:");
const apellido = prompt("Dime tu apellido:");
const edad = prompt("Dime tu edad:");

var alu1 = new Alumno(nombre, apellido, edad);
```

Con `<input />` sería:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre">
<input type="text" id="apellido">
<input type="number" id="edad">
```

y con JS:

```
function getData(){
    const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    const apellido = document.getElementById("apellido");
    const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
    
    return {nombre, apellido, edad};
}

const {nombre, apellido, edad} = getData();

var alu1 = new Alumno(nombre, apellido, edad);
alu1.Matricular(305);
alu1.Imprimir();
```

Para que el usuario añada más alumnos podrías hacer un formulario en el que el usuario escriba los datos de los alumnos, y podrías poner un botón que añada más campos para más alumnos al formulario. Ya es cosa de que le vayas dando vueltas y probando cosas.